# How can I prevent TinyMCE from adding CDATA to <script> tags and from commenting out <style> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

Let's put aside the issues of allowing `<script>` content inside a Web editor; I'm perfectly aware of them.

What I want is to allow `<style>` and `<script>` elements inside the text content, the issue is that, whenever I do this, TinyMCE changes them to:

```
<style><!-- th{width:80px} --></style>
```

and the script content is changed to:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
$.address.unbind();
// ]]></script>
```

On my TinyMCE init configuration, I have:

```
valid_elements : "*[*]",
extended_valid_elements : "*[*],script[charset|defer|language|src|type],style",
custom_elements: "*[*],script[charset|defer|language|src|type],style",
valid_children : "+body[style],+body[script]",
verify_html : false,
media_strict: false
```

But I can't seem to find a way to prevent TinyMCE from **disabling** the `<style>` and `<script>` elements.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to remove the <!-- --> from style tags within tinyMCE?

Comment: From what i'm reading it looks like TinyMCE produces XHTML and wraps the style contents in a comment to keep any XML parser from failing to parse the contents (as all browsers support the comment syntax).

Edit: Have you tried using `cleanup : false`?

Comment: @BenRacicot why do you want to remove <!-- --> from style tags ?

Comment: Browsers seem to be handling them uniquely.

Comment: @BenRacicot What does it mean ? Please use @ AndreaLigios in comment or I won't be notified

Comment: I have encountered this same issue in the TinyMCE contained within WordPress. Even though I was able to write a PHP function that excluded certain tags from being stripped by the editor (similar to what you have here), I found that the comment code was always there. I couldn't figure out how to get rid of it. But I think I know why it's there. I believe this is to prevent the code within the tags from being wrapped in paragraph tags, as TinyMCE does by default for each line break. So I left the comment code in there since my scripts still worked fine on the front end.

Comment: @BenRacicot have you tried removing the code that I have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @naimshaikh Hey Naim, I have not tried it because you didn't specify if it works. I'm reluctant to remove minified script but will try it on Monday.

Comment: @BenRacicot I tried it on my side and it was working, at least give it one try...

Answer (score 12):

I would recommend avoiding any direct customization to third party libraries if it can be avoided.  Instead I added a custom node filter to the editors serializer during initialization by adding the following to the config object passed into the tinymce construction call:

```
init_instance_callback : function(editor) {
    // jw: this code is heavily borrowed from tinymce.jquery.js:12231 but modified so that it will
    //     just remove the escaping and not add it back.
    editor.serializer.addNodeFilter('script,style', function(nodes, name) {
        var i = nodes.length, node, value, type;

        function trim(value) {
            /*jshint maxlen:255 */
            /*eslint max-len:0 */
            return value.replace(/(<!--\[CDATA\[|\]\]-->)/g, '\n')
                    .replace(/^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]*$/g, '')
                    .replace(/^\s*((<!--)?(\s*\/\/)?\s*<!\[CDATA\[|(<!--\s*)?\/\*\s*<!\[CDATA\[\s*\*\/|(\/\/)?\s*<!--|\/\*\s*<!--\s*\*\/)\s*[\r\n]*/gi, '')
                    .replace(/\s*(\/\*\s*\]\]>\s*\*\/(-->)?|\s*\/\/\s*\]\]>(-->)?|\/\/\s*(-->)?|\]\]>|\/\*\s*-->\s*\*\/|\s*-->\s*)\s*$/g, '');
        }
        while (i--) {
            node = nodes[i];
            value = node.firstChild ? node.firstChild.value : '';

            if (value.length > 0) {
                node.firstChild.value = trim(value);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Hopefully this will help others stuck in the same boat.

Comment: Works just perfect, can't believe I'm the first vote for such 'done-right' answer

Comment: Working perfectly! And keeps code clean without unnecessary modifications! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try altering the **tinymce.min.js**

```
,f.addNodeFilter("script,style",function(e,t){function n(e){return e.replace(/(<!--\[CDATA\[|\]\]-->)/g,"\n").replace(/^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]*$/g,"").replace(/^\s*((<!--)?(\s*\/\/)?\s*<!\[CDATA\[|(<!--\s*)?\/\*\s*<!\[CDATA\[\s*\*\/|(\/\/)?\s*<!--|\/\*\s*<!--\s*\*\/)\s*[\r\n]*/gi,"").replace(/\s*(\/\*\s*\]\]>\s*\*\/(-->)?|\s*\/\/\s*\]\]>(-->)?|\/\/\s*(-->)?|\]\]>|\/\*\s*-->\s*\*\/|\s*-->\s*)\s*$/g,"")}for(var r=e.length,i,o,a;r--;)i=e[r],o=i.firstChild?i.firstChild.value:"","script"===t?(a=i.attr("type"),a&&i.attr("type","mce-no/type"==a?null:a.replace(/^mce\-/,"")),o.length>0&&(i.firstChild.value="// <![CDATA[\n"+n(o)+"\n// ]]>")):o.length>0&&(i.firstChild.value="<!--\n"+n(o)+"\n-->")}),f.addNodeFilter("#comment",function(e){for(var t=e.length,n;t--;)n=e[t],0===n.value.indexOf("[CDATA[")?(n.name="#cdata",n.type=4,n.value=n.value.replace(/^\[CDATA\[|\]\]$/g,"")):0===n.value.indexOf("mce:protected ")&&(n.name="#text",n.type=3,n.raw=!0,n.value=unescape(n.value).substr(14))})
```

Please, find and remove the above line of code from the file.

Comment: This causes issues with the type attribute. It now adds `mce-` to all type attributes. It seems to remove the `<!-- -->` from style tags its breaking `<script>`

Answer (score 2):

when you store tinymce content, simply remove these tags from output similar like this:

```
$tinyOutput = str_replace(array("// <![CDATA[", "// ]]>"), array("", ""), $_POST['tinyOutput']);
```

..then save to db..

Comment: I prefer this beacause I don't want to alter `tinymce.min.js` code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to remove the following code for disabling script tag formating:

```
,o.length>0&&(i.firstChild.value="// <![CDATA[\n"+n(o)+"\n// ]]>")
```

And for formating on style tag, you should remove:

```
&&(i.firstChild.value="<!--\n"+n(o)+"\n-->")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `&lt;` in place of `<` for the style and script tags. That way tinymce will not recognize style and script tags.

For example:

For style:

```
&lt;style>th{width:80px}&lt;/style>
```

For script:

```
&lt;script>
$.address.unbind();
&lt;/script>
```